# Excel: When a data validation is changed, copy that value to a specific cell

Tags: vba, excel, validation

On sheet 1 Cell 15 I have a cell which is a data validation to choose a cluster, I would like it so when I select a value from the drop-down it copies & pastes to another cell in another sheet which is read by formulas.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "I15" Then
    With Sheets("Team Holiday Calender").Cells(2, "C") '.End(xlup)(2)
    Sheets("Front").Range("I15").Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End If

End Sub
```

Is what i currently have, but it doesn't do the job.

Am i making this too hard for myself?

Comment: Why `xlPasteValidation`? If you want to paste the value, `xlPasteValues`

Comment: You're missing an `End With` before `End If`.

Comment: `Target.Address = "I15"` should be `Target.Address = "$I$15"` , also `Sheets("Front").Range("I15").Copy` should be `Target.Copy` (just cleaner on the eye, and take advantage of `Worksheet_Change` built-in parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it as,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address(0, 0) = "I15" Then
        With Sheets("Team Holiday Calender")
            .Cells(2, "C") = Target.Value
        end with
    End If

End Sub
```

Direct .Value transfer does not copy formatting along like a Copy & Paste does but you should be able to accommodate for that or switch to a Copy & Paste.

Comment: what happened to your `.rows.count` ? ;) Question from the MVP, you prefer to check `Target.Address =...` or `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I15")) Is Nothing Then` any difference in performance ?

Comment: That code does paste in the C column but not in C2, it goes into cell C39 then continues down from there.

Comment: OK, you had `.End(xlUp)` commented out but I thought you wanted to paste into the next blank cell in column C. Fixed  above to **always** post in C2.

Comment: @ShaiRado - `If Intersect(...` would cover multiple cells in target but sometimes you just want a single cell. Seems the OP only wants to paste into 'Team Holiday Calender'!C2 which would be impossible (or at least problematic) with multiple cell value transfer.